# What kind of windows are these?

Tags: windows

I live in a high-rise. This high-rise is right next to the highway, so there's a ton of noise.

I have double-paned "outside" windows, but then I have this removable inner-frame. 
[image: Window, side view]

It uses these brackets to hold it in place:
[image: Bracket]
With these brackets, I can "lift" the window and it slides right out.

The entire thing looks like this:
[image: Entire window]

Comment: I think you are describing a double-pane outside window plus an single-pane inside window that is removable. Which of these are you asking to identify? For the double-pane have you looked along the Al between the panes for etched markings?

Comment: How does this relate to Home Improvement? What problem or issue are you trying to solve by knowing what type of window this is?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it A couple things:

Comment: @JimmyFix-it  I'm trying to figure out how to buy more of these -- they do acoustic dampening, and not all my windows are like this.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it  I'm also trying to tint these windows. If I can remove the inner panel and disassemble it safely, tinting becomes 1000x easier. If I can't, well, shit.

Comment: By the looks of it, those are commercial aluminum frame windows that are exterior glazed. If you are looking to replace the outer sealed unit as a whole, you will not only need special equipment on the outside of the bldg to replace that outer glass, but will likely have to involve several parties such as the condo owner, window supplier/ manufacturer, contractor, and/or others.
You'll probably want to look into contacting the window supplier/manuf. to buy replacement inner-frames otherwise you will run into a lot of issues 'disassembling' those inners. They are not designed to be broken up

Comment: @AnonyTech Replacing the outside is basically impossible. I wanted to replace the inner-frames -- they're actually removable, but I can't find anyone to do the dies for them and build the windows. :(